# Firestore Transaction contention without write attempts?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, transactions, google-cloud-functions

I am analyzing logs that show the error "Too much contention on these documents. Please try again". What is strange here is that logs within the transactions never executed, which seems to indicate the transactions never made a write attempt. In the below example, the error says there was contention at `runTransaction` though "Updating documents" is not in any of the logs.

If there was no write operation performed on the documents (note these transactions are the only way these documents are updated), how is it possible there was contention? That is, if there were never any writes, given transactions allow reads from outside of the transaction how could the below code lead to contention? Obviously I understand that a few of these transactions on the same documents trying to write would trigger contention, but in this case, "Updating documents" never executed so it isn't possible there was ever a write attempt.

Put more simply: for there to be contention, there needs to be write calls; but for there to be write calls, "Updating documents" needed to trigger; "Updating documents" did not trigger, and therefore there couldn't have been write calls, so there shouldn't have been contention.

```
return db.runTransaction((transaction) => {
   return transaction.get(query).then((querySnapshot) => {
      console.log("Updating documents");
      [transaction code here to update documents]
   }
});
```

Comment: Can you check if [Firebase transaction and data contention link](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/transaction-data-contention) answer your question?

Comment: Thanks - I read the docs before posting this, but my question is that since the above code did not execute any writes, how could there have been contention? Firestore transactions allow parallel reads, so I'm confused how the above could reach a contention state.

Comment: Would you kindly add a reproducible code so that we could test it on our end?

Comment: The above is the key reproducible code - the only difference is that in the actual code, in the brackets noted it sets a document. I should also point out that this may not be an easy to reproduce error - I run the function over 30K times a day, and it has had 2 errors in the past 3 weeks. Therefore, it seems this might be more of a logical question than one to empirically test, though I am certainly open to providing any further information that could be helpful.

Comment: @Redneys, I removed my answer because it seems your problem is more like a debug issue on your side, a possible hacking of your database, or a bug in the latest updates to the firebase library.